# Operator overload function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I received an error message when compiling the operator-(double value) function code shown below. The code is merely to find The distance of a point from the origin. Please enlighten me on where i've gone wrong and show me how you resolve it. Let me know if you require more info. Thanks!

Compilation error msg:

```
Point.cpp: In member function ‘CS170::Point CS170::Point::operator- 
(double)’:

Point.cpp:187:49: error: no matching function for call to 

‘CS170::Point::Point(double)’

 return Point(sqrt(((x * value) + (y * value))));
                                               ^
```

The code is used to achieve this in the driver file:

`pt3 = pt1 - 2;`

```
  Point Point::operator-(double value)
{

    Point temp;
    temp=sqrt(((x * value) + (y * value)));
    return temp ;

}
```

//list.h file

```
 class Point
  {
    public:
     // Constructors (2)
  explicit Point(double x, double y); 

  Point();

   double getX() const;

   double getY() const;

   Point operator+(const Point& other)const ;

   Point& operator+(double value);


   Point operator*(double value) ;

   Point operator%(double angle);


   double operator-(const Point& other)const ;

   Point operator-(double value);

   Point operator^(const Point& other);

   Point operator+=(double value);
   Point& operator+=(const Point& other) ;

   Point& operator++();
   Point operator++(int); 

   Point& operator--(); 
   Point operator--(int); 

   Point& operator-();


        // Overloaded operators (14 member functions)
   friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Point 
  &point );
    friend std::istream &operator>>( std::istream  &input, Point 
  &point );

    // Overloaded operators (2 friend functions)

private:
  double x; // The x-coordinate of a Point
  double y; // The y-coordinate of a Point

    // Helper functions
  double DegreesToRadians(double degrees) const;
  double RadiansToDegrees(double radians) const;
   };

 // Point& Add(const Point& other); // Overloaded operators (2 non-member, 
 non-friend functions)
    // Point& Multiply(const Point& other);
    Point operator+( double value, const Point& other );
    Point operator-( double value, const Point& other );
```

Comment: A point is a coordinate containing two values: X and Y. How is the result of `sqrt(((x * value) + (y * value)))` supposed to be split into the two values needed for a point?

Comment: I find it extremely confusing that you want to use `operator-` to calculate the distance between two points. The expectation is that `operator-` is the inverse to `operator+` but in your case the two are doing two completely unrelated things. Tbh I think it is cases like that why some ppl think operator overloading is a bad thing ;)

Comment: Ye you're right. Didn't realised be4.. lol..

Comment: not everthing has to be an operator, a good rule of thumb is: When there is only the slightest chance of misunderstanding for the user, then make it a member function and give it a proper name

Comment: @user463035818 well its an assignment from my school. I'm merely following their requirements.

Comment: no problem, I hope I could convince you that this is a bad design and you know what you are doing there. We all have to deal with requirements that sometimes force us to do strange things ;)

Comment: I know man. thanks tho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Point` class constructor takes two parameters, `x`, and `y`, whereas the result of `sqrt` is a single value. If you want to use the same value twice, then either make a constructor which accepts a single value, or assign the result of `sqrt` to a variable, and then pass that variable into the constructor twice.

Comment: Hmm ok, mind showing me how to resolve it. coz i'm not really sure.

Comment: @user10995546 just updated the answer with what you need to do.

Comment: x=sqrt(x * value);
y=sqrt(y * value);
return *this;

Comment: Something like this ^?

Comment: The problem suggests you should be returning `double` instead of `Point`, which means you declared the function wrong.

Comment: @user10995546, no, `sqrt` takes two parameters as well. Store the result of `sqrt` into one variable, and pass the same variable into the constructor, twice. Assuming that's the logic you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a `Point` Constructor that takes a `double` parameter.

```
Point (double d){
   //whatever logic of point construction.
};
```

to solve the error in line.

```
temp=sqrt(((x * value) + (y * value)));
```

But that would end up constructing a point like.

```
Point P = 5;
```

some where else and you may not want that to happen.

in your shoes I would make it explicit constructor.

```
explicit Point(double d){
   //whatever logic of point construction.
};
```

that way you would end up initializing your point this way needing explicit casting from `double` to `Point`

```
Point P1 = (Point)5;
Point P2 = (Point)sqrt(((x * value) + (y * value)));
```

and finally I'll argue about the `Point - double` subtraction logic you are doing in your function.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to construct a point from a single value. In cases where it is required, it would be better to be more explicit by forcing the caller to pass in the same value twice.

Comment: you are right but it might have some intention to "maybe" in a default direction with only length or whatever logic he has