# Operator unary overloading function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am stuck on a problem with unary operator overloading. So in the code shown below, i am basically not getting the desired result that matches my school. See below for more info. There are some restrictions on the function, i can't add any parameters otherwise it gives me a compilation error. So what should i do about it? Do let me know if you require more info. Thanks!

```
    Point& Point::operator-() 
{

    x = -x;
    y = -y;
    return *this;

}
```

Here's the result:

********** My Unary test **********

pt1 = (3,4)

pt2 = -pt1

pt1 = (-3,-4)

pt2 = (-3,-4)

pt3 = (-3,4)

pt4 = - - -pt3

pt3 = (3,-4)

pt4 = (3,-4)

********** School's Unary test **********

pt1 = (3, 4)

pt2 = -pt1

pt1 = (3, 4)//

pt2 = (-3, -4)

pt3 = (-3, 4)

pt4 = - - -pt3

pt3 = (-3, 4)//

pt4 = (3, -4)

Driver file

```
  void UnaryTest(void)
{
cout << "\n********** Unary test ********** " << endl;

Point pt1(3, 4);
cout << "pt1 = " << pt1 << endl;
Point pt2 = -pt1;
cout << "pt2 = -pt1" << endl;

cout << "pt1 = " << pt1 << endl;
cout << "pt2 = " << pt2 << endl;

cout << endl;

Point pt3(-3, 4);
cout << "pt3 = " << pt3 << endl;
Point pt4 = - - -pt3;
cout << "pt4 = - - -pt3" << endl;

cout << "pt3 = " << pt3 << endl;
cout << "pt4 = " << pt4 << endl;
}
```

list.h file

```
  class Point
  {
   public:

  explicit Point(double x, double y); 

  Point();

   double getX() const;

   double getY() const;

   Point operator+(const Point& other)const ;

   Point& operator+(double value);


   Point operator*(double value) ;

   Point operator%(double angle);


   double operator-(const Point& other)const ;

   Point operator-(double value);

   Point operator^(const Point& other);

   Point& operator+=(double value);
   Point& operator+=(const Point& other) ;

   Point& operator++();
   Point operator++(int); 

   Point& operator--(); 
   Point operator--(int); 

   Point& operator-() ;


        // Overloaded operators (14 member functions)
   friend std::ostream &operator<<( std::ostream &output, const Point 
  &point );
    friend std::istream &operator>>( std::istream  &input, Point 
  &point );

    // Overloaded operators (2 friend functions)

 private:
  double x; // The x-coordinate of a Point
  double y; // The y-coordinate of a Point

    // Helper functions
  double DegreesToRadians(double degrees) const;
  double RadiansToDegrees(double radians) const;
};

 // Point& Add(const Point& other); // Overloaded operators (2 non-member, 
 non-friend functions)
    // Point& Multiply(const Point& other);
    Point operator+( double value, const Point& other );
    Point operator*( double value, const Point& other );
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator overload function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54531189/operator-overload-function)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher exactly. how do i write in such a way that i do not?

Comment: Not the same duplicate, although probably from the same original homework.

Comment: Its not a duplicate man. ye its the same homework

Comment: Please explain in which way it is different from the proposed duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The prototype is:

```
Point operator-(double value);
```

But your implementation is:

```
Point& Point::operator-()
```

This cannot work (note the reference and the different arguments!).

Also you should not modify the object in place for this operator. Instead, you should have this:

```
Point operator-() const;
```

And then:

```
Point Point::operator-() const
{
    return Point(-x, -y);
}
```